# Org code evaluate: Preserve table headers when evaluating awk code

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

There is a table of savings account balances in my org file as follows:

```
#+NAME: accounts
| Person   | Balance |
|----------+---------|
| Babur    |    1000 |
| Humayun  |    2000 |
| Akbar    |    3000 |
```

Now, my org-mode awk source block calculates annual simple interest at 7% rate and prints it.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC awk :stdin accounts
    {
            print $1, 0.07*$2
    }
#+END_SRC
```

If at all there is a feature to specify a custom column header, it is great. Or at least i like org-mode to preserve the header.

```
#+RESULTS:
| Person  |    0 |
| Babur   |   70 |
| Humayun |  140 |
| Akbar   |  210 |
```

But as one can see, the table header is also taken for calculation, resulting in `0` value.
I desire to have my output as,

```
#+RESULTS:
| Person  | Interest |
|---------+----------|
| Babur   |       70 |
| Humayun |      140 |
| Akbar   |      210 |
```

Is there a way in org-mode to preserve the column header or print a custom one?

Comment: Unfortunately, the Babel Awk implementation (`ob-awk.el`) is very limited. In the `stdin` format, it converts tables to (essentially) name-value tuples, it does not obey the `:colnames` header AFAICT, and it throws away `hline`s so it loses the structure of the table. You can write ad-hoc headers of your own in a `BEGIN` block in the awk script itself, but you cannot get rid of the original header (unless you delete it from the table). I'd say you'd be better off with a `python` code block.

Comment: @NickD, can you make that as the answer putting the point across: org-babel does not support the header argument `colnames ` for awk

Comment: Why do you insist that table be piped to `awk`, and no other way.  A simple `TBLFM` will do an `interest` column easily.

Comment: the purpose is to explain awk command's functionality to my students. Since the input & output can be juxtaposed in one page in org mode, it is easier to demo awk using it.

Comment: If the intention is to teach `awk`, I think adding a `hidden layer` of `org` mechanics would really "fool" students.  What  I mean is this ... unless your instructional material SHOWS how `awk` "destructures" an Org table, the instructional material would  be incomplete.  The intention is not to judge you ... but to emphasise how  instrucutional materials are to be structured.  I am not familiar with `awk`, but I will use your question as an excuse to teach myself `awk` ....

Comment: Show how `awk` "destructures" an Org table using  [`|` (= `pipe` )   as a `field-separator`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Field-Separators). .... and how the script you create identifies and  `"passes-through"` `hline` and `column headers`.  So your script will some variant of  [isnumeric](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Isnumeric-Function) and you have to device an `awk` rule  that tests for `hline`.